# Maven dependencies regarding javax.persistence JAR?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 JPA. I am confused regarding *javax.persistence* JAR. I found below two Maven dependencies on Google. Please tell me which one is required in below two dependencies?

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first of those `javax.persistence.persistence-api` is the API Jar, which defines vendor-neutral interfaces which your application should be working with.

The second is the EclipseLink implementation of that API.

It is possible to remove references to the first `javax.persistence` dependency and just use the EclipseLink jar. However there is a good reason not to.

Writing and compiling your code against the vendor-neutral `javax.persistence` API ensures that your application code is portable to different persistence providers. For instance if you wished to switch to Hibernate, then you could put that in your pom.xml and remove the `org.eclipse` dependency, without changing any of your application code.

However, there's an extra little detail you should change. To ensure that your application can switch between persistence providers, the 'implementation' dependency should only be used at runtime. Otherwise, vendor-specific code could easily make its way into your codebase. Add the following to your `org.eclipse` dependency and see whether your application compiles.

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

As a result of that, you may find that your application has EclipseLink-specific code in it. This means that you could not change persistence provider without changing your codebase.

Whether that's a problem is up to you. ;)

Comment: Steve, i tried using javax.persistence jar alone. But i keep getting some errors while running the application saying that 'NoSuchMethodError'

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can't use `javax.persistence` on its own, because it does not provide an implementation. Either use `org.eclipse` on its own or use both with `org.eclipse` defined as `runtime` scoped.

Comment: Steve, Thanks for your answer. What does runtime scope mean? Also , is ejb3.persistence jar also implements java persistence API ?

Comment: It means that it won't be used at compile-time. Therefore the `javax.persistence` API will be used for compilation, keeping your code vendor-neutral.

Comment: okay, tomorrow if i want ot use any other implemenation then i can just change the vendor secific dependency right? Also do i need to keep ejb3 persistence jar? is it also implementation of javax persistence API ?

Comment: That's the theory. :)  Have a look inside your ejb3 persistence jar. It may well also have the same API classes. For example, the Hibernate `ejb-persistence-*.jar` libraries contain it. As does `javaee-api-*.jar`. If you have both Hibernate and EclipseLink jars in your dependencies, you should definitely remove one of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which is the lastest one and compact with hibernate 4. Also latest version of hibernate support jpa 2.1.0 please check this [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3aversions-panel)

Comment: Sureshkumar thanks for your reply. If we have this jar then ejb3.persistence jar is not required right? because it comes along with hibernate4 entity manager jar.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to include that dependency explicitly, it is in Hibernate pom and will be added transitively

Comment: Evgeniy, i am using hibernate 4.0.2 version. But i dont see persistence jar in its pom.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse open pom's dependency hierarchy and check there