# Eclipse Maven - Build Project with Multiple Module dont find JPA Annotations(@Id, @Table ecc)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jpa

In Eclipse, i've created a project with packaging POM that contains 3 Project (i'm creating a client-server application):

It is composed to 3 modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>LANAlertClient</module>
    <module>LANAlertServer</module>
    <module>LANAlertService</module>
  </modules>
```

- LANAlertClient -> Will be my client
- LANAlertServer -> Will me My Server
- LanAlertservice -> Will contains all the shared classes (such as RMI Interfaces, Socket Object etc)

Now i have created the 3 project and all depends from LANAlert (that is the packaging POM).

Server have Services artifact and Client have Services Artifact:

Now, when i run **mvn clean package** on LANAlert (that is the container) it successfully compile **LANServices** and **LANClient** but ***fail*** with LANServer, that have JPA annotations, all errors are like this:

```
package javax.persistence does not exist
error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Entity
```

Looking on the classes that have that annotations i have no errors, and all import are correct.

I've tried to include that dependecies on LANAlert(the container) pom.xml file and on LANServer pom.xml file, but the results is the same.

Could someone help me to resolve this?

**UPDATE: pom.xml of LANServer.**

**CAUTION**: Before to move the project with that structure i was LANServer as indipendent project. I've just tried to execute mvn clean on it and the error is the same. If i simply run it in Eclipse: Run as -> Java Application the server works

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>it.mycorp</groupId>
        <artifactId>LANAlert</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>LANAlertServer</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.mycorp</groupId>
            <artifactId>LANAlertService</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>it.mycorp.main.ServerEntryPoint</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you post `pom.xml` from `LANServer`?

Comment: I've solved.... look my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that issue, was my fault.

I've missing the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

When i simply run it with Run As -> Java Application for sure i was not packaging nothing, and i dont have look that error before packaging it.

Comment: beware that this is the EclipseLink implementation distributable. If you want the jpa (implemetation agnostic) one you should use the javax.persistence group id. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523445/maven-dependencies-regarding-javax-persistence-jar